# How to generate a list with repeating key from a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a dictionary

```
a_dict = {1: 1, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 4}
```

I want to create a list such that the dict key appears value number of times:

```
a_list = [1, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

My current code is like this:

```
a_list = []

for key in a_dict.keys():
    for value in a_dict.values():
```

I do not know what to do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in a concise way using a list comprehension with nested `for` loops:

```
>>> d = {1: 1, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 4}
>>> [k for k, v in d.items() for _ in range(v)]
[1, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

However, please note that **`dict` is an unordered data structure** and therefore the order of keys in the resulting list is arbitrary.

May I ask for which purpose you want to use the resulting list? Maybe there is a better way of solving the actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
a={1: 1, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 4}
list=[]
for key, value in a.items():
    list.extend([key] * value)
print list
```

Answer (score 2):

A rather ugly list comprehension:

```
[vals for tuplei in d.items() for vals in [tuplei[0]] * tuplei[1]]
```

yields

```
[1, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

Slightly more readable (resulting in the same output):

```
[vals for (keyi, vali) in d.items() for vals in [keyi] * vali]
```

An itertools solution:

```
import itertools

list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[k]*v for k, v in d.items()]))
```

will also give

```
[1, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

Short explanation:

```
[[k]*v for k, v in d.items()]
```

creates

```
[[1], [4, 4], [5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6, 6]]
```

which is then flattened.

Answer (score 1):

You are not mssing much!

```
a_dict = {1: 1, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 4}
a_list = []
for key, value in a_dict.items():
    a_list.extend([key]*value)
print(a_list)
```

Comment: I did it 9 seconds before you! :D

Comment: What shall I do in this case ? delete my answer or leave it here? I don't know all the "best behavior" yet :P

Comment: leave it man! it's funny we came up with the same answer, almost at the same time. Maybe a moderator will delete it... or maybe they'll delete mine! Let's just enjoy it while it lasts :D

Answer (score 0):

```
dict = {1: 1, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 4}
list=[]
for key, value in dict.items():
  i = 0
  while i < value:
    list.append(key)
    i+=1

print(list)
```

Should do the trick